# Iframe is not compatible in mobile devices(especially Iphone)

Tags: .net, iframe, pdf-viewer

I am using Iframe to view the PDF in my web and mobile applications. It works fine in web applications but not working in iOS devices.

I am trying to use the iframe for IOS as well. I need to know whether iframe will work on IOS? How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Their a JS library called viewer.js that will render a pdf via JavaScript in an iframe